# Select all rows except if this condition is true

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't quite think straight on this one.

I'm trying to compose an SQL query for the following:

```
shared_id | user_id | processed
1181      | 1       | 1
1181      | 1       | 1
1181      | 1       | 0
1181      | 2       | 1
1181      | 2       | 0
1182      | 2       | 0
```

I want to select all rows where:

- shared_id = 1181
- user_id != 1 if processed = 0

So the above would return a count of 4, because in the third row, the user_id is 1 and processed is 0. If processed = 1, then this row should be included.

I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM $table_name 
WHERE shared_id = '{$shared_id}'
AND (user_id != '1' AND processed = '0')
```

However, this isn't working as I'd have expected. Any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM $table_name 
WHERE shared_id = '{$shared_id}'
AND (processed != '0' OR user_id != '1')
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus, That works. Is it common practice to not use AND inside brackets, then? Saying the above query out loud still doesn't make sense to me, but it does work.

Comment: @JamesKemp, the `OR` clause is only in parenthesis because those two expressions have to be evaluated together.